# What should Minecraft mod crashes be flagged as?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, flags, minecraft

So recently I have found a question about Minecraft crashing due to mods (which is off topic). But when I flag it and the post closes I don't see my name in the "who flagged it as off topic" list. Am I using the wrong flag? Please tell me what I should flag questions like that as.

Comment: I think this comes down to the difference between flagging and voting. flagging is just alerting other users who can vote about it of the issue, but does not actually take part in the vote. Once you have 3000 reputation you'll be able to vote to close instead of flagging. ANd then it'll be your name in the list of people who closed it.

Comment: Ok. My other question was what should I flag them as?

Comment: @Alex Flag -> Should be closed -> Off topic -> Other, and write a short description stating that technical support for modded copies of Minecraft is off-topic. We don't have a default close reason that fits it so we use 'Other'

Comment: @Robotnik sorry for late reply, I can't write a desc for some reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you flag to close as off topic, your flag sends it to the "Close Vote" Review Queue. Higher rep users review the queue to determine if it should be closed or not. They can also skip the queue and just vote to close on the question itself (which will also send the question into the Close Vote Review Queue). Only the higher rep users' close votes show up in the close message.

You can read more about [close and reopen vote privileges in the help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).